# Move every other value from array into a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have two one-dimensional arrays, `a` and `b`. `a` has values and `b` is empty. The length of `a` is an even number. I'd like to remove every other value from `a` and move them to `b`, in the same order as they were placed in `a`.

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], b = [];
```

becomes

```
var a = [1, 3, 5], b = [2, 4, 6];
```

I figured that `filter` would do the trick but I'm not that happy with the performance of it since the average length of `a` is 300-400.

```
b = a.filter((i, idx) => {
    return idx % 2 == 0;
});
a = a.filter((i, idx) => {
    return idx % 2 == 1;
});
```

I've also been looking at lodash to see if that library had anything that might help me and the only function that's near what I'm looking for is [`_.chunk(array, \[size=1\])`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#chunk).

I appreciate any and all help to help me figure out a better, faster way to do this.

Comment: Filtering a small array of 400 elements should be nearly instantaneous. What do you mean you're not happy with the performance? Are you noticing delays? It could be done in a single iteration, but it won't make much difference

Comment: You could benchmark the given answers for performance, would be really interesting to see how lodash performs against vanilla js e.g..

Comment: @slezica I agree it would not make a noticable difference with 400 elements. Still, if this gets executed a lot of times, it could.

Comment: @Hinrich Great idea, I'll set up a jsperf test with all of your answers.

Comment: Here's a performance test for all of your answers, thank you so much for your help! https://jsperf.com/move-every-other-value-from-array-into-a-new-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vanilla JS ES5, simple and clean.

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], b = [];

for(var i = a.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if(i % 2 === 1) {
    b.unshift(a.splice(i, 1)[0])
  }
}
```

Basically, it is iterating through `a` backwards, and if the condition is true splicing the item und adding it as first item of `b`.

Answer (score 4):

Since you mentioned lodash you could do this with [_.partition](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#partition):

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
let b = [];
let i = -1;

[a, b] = _.partition(a, (item) => i++ % 2);

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Partition's predicate is the identity function, which doesn't include the index of the item, so this comes with a compromise of an external index `i`.

Of course, you could always wrap this functionality into it's own function:

```js
const splitEvenOdd = (array, i = -1) => _.partition(array, (item) => i++ % 2);

let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
let b = [];

[a, b] = splitEvenOdd(a);

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

To loop through the source once, the values can be added to a specific array depending on the index. For example:

```js
const source = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

let arrs = [[],[]];
for(let i = 0; i< source.length; i++)
 arrs[i%2].push(source[i]);
let [a,b] = arrs;  
  
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Alternatively, if it's important to alter the original arrays, `a` can be filled in a direct iteration, since the index being processed is always ahead of the one being filled:

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], b= [];

for(let i = 0; i< a.length; i++)
 (i % 2 ? b : a)[Math.floor(i/2)] = a[i];
  
a.splice(a.length/2);
  
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Comment: Excellent answer with vanilla JS... I like it much better than relying on a library.

Answer (score 1):

The best performance you can get for this is 0(n) or linear time since you have to iterate through the entire array. What may help is reducing the number of loops

```
var a=[];
var b=[];
function splitArray(arr)
{
    for (var i=0;i<arr.length;++i)
        {
            if (arr[i]%2 == 0)
                b.push(arr[i]);
            else
                a.push(arr[i]); 
        }
}
```

What this does is reduces the number of times you have to iterate through the original array from 2 to 1